# Bash script for files in directory (backup)

Tags: bash, file, backup

So, I need to write a script in bash which will backup files of directory.

Script gets files (list of files for backup) as arguments, and last argument must be target folder (directory). If target folder doesnt exist, must be created by script.

I was planning to use for loop for moving through list of arguments (files), but I dont know how to use last argument, and check if it exists.

Call of script:

```
./myScript.sh file1 file2 file3... fileN target_folder
```

Thanks. :)

I started this:

```
#!/bin/bash

#doing backup of files passed as list of arguments.

if [ "$#" lt "2" ]
then 
    echo usage:  "./myScript.sh <list of arguments -files for backup.>"
    exit
fi
for arg in "$#"
do
    if #last argument exist as folder in directory, just copy all files in
            else #make targer folder and copy all files in 

done
```

Comment: it sounds like you are rewriting `cp` ?

Comment: yes... task is pretty plain. i need to use cp for doing that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`getopts`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial) and pass the directory as a named argument:

```
./myScript.sh -d target_folder file1 file2 file3... fileN
```

Comment: i need to use eval for that last argument (target folder).. -.-'

Comment: I fail to see what's preventing you from using `eval` on a named argument.